# Using of unicode with a TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe

I`d like to define a string constant with mixed greek and cyrillic symbols. Something like this

```
const
  some_const = 'cyrillic symbols' + $03C9;
```

where `$03C9` is the lower case letter *omega* from [there](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/greekchart.html).
Maybe, I`ll should make `some_const` a variable in a datamodule and initialize it.

```
//datamodule
var
  some_const = 'cyrillic symbols' + some_function_to_make_string($03C9);
```

So, what is a correct function for `some_function_to_make_string(code : Word)`?

Can I use this `some_const` with a *TStringGrid.Cells[aCol, aRow]*?

Comment: I posted it by chance... :)

Comment: I realize what Delphi documentation is sloppy, but you still obligated to [read it](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Character_Strings). `const some_const = 'альфа' + Chr($03C9);` or `const some_const = 'альфа' + #$03C9;`